# Profile 2 different types with single edit form

Tags: forms, users

I am using the [profile2 module](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) to create different types of information for the user.  One of these profile types are filled in on the registration page.

What I am trying to accomplish is combining the registration form profile with another profile so that they can be edited on the same form page.

For example: The fields of Profile-Registration and Profile-Info must all be editable on www.website.com/form/%user/edit.  These fields are rendered with views, and are working perfectly.  It is just the editing I am trying to figure out.  I am not sure how to go about achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

It could be accomplished using [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels):

> The Panels module allows a site administrator to create customized
>   layouts for multiple uses. At its core it is a drag and drop content
>   manager that lets you visually design a layout and place content
>   within that layout. Integration with other systems allows you to
>   create nodes that use this, landing pages that use this, and even
>   override system pages such as taxonomy and the node page so that you
>   can customize the layout of your site with very fine grained
>   permissions.

and [Profile2 Panels Module:](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_panels)

> Page Manager (Panels) support for Profile2.
>
> With this module you can take over Profile2 paths with Page Manager.
>   Now it is possible to theme your Profile2 edit and view pages with
>   Panels.

If you're not familiar with panels, there are numerous resources and tutorials out there

Comment: If I try to add a context (profile2 edit form), I get the following AJAX HTTP Error: http://postimg.org/image/r4e9a7o8d/.  I then have to delete the whole variant, because I keep getting the error no matter what I do next.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with that module, only its existance - this error might be best as a new question here, or in the issues queue for the module